# spring-data-cassandra 1.5.0.M1 BeanInstantiationException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-cassandra

When running spring boot application, getting following BeanInstantiationException:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sampleCassandraApplication': 
    Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository':
    Error creating bean with name 'customerRepository': 
    Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cassandraTemplate' while setting bean property 'cassandraTemplate'; 
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'cassandraTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/cassandra/CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.class]: 
    Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'cassandraTemplate' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/cassandra/CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.class]: 
    Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'session' parameter 0: 
    Error creating bean with name 'cassandraConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/cassandra/CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.class]: 
    Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'cassandraConverter' parameter 0: 
    Error creating bean with name 'cassandraMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/cassandra/CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; 
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
    Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.CassandraMappingContext]: 
    Factory method 'cassandraMapping' threw exception;
     nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'cassandraMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/cassandra/CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.class]: 
    Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
    Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.CassandraMappingContext]: 
    Factory method 'cassandraMapping' threw exception;
```

nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE;

When went into the source, found this:

[image: Error]

Comment: Please make sure to use `1.5.0.M1` for `spring-data-cassandra` and `spring-cql` artifacts. See [here](https://spring.io/blog/2016/07/27/spring-data-release-train-ingalls-m1-released) for all versions and how to set up `Ingalls-M1` with Spring Boot.

Comment: @mp911de Yes I have configured 1.5.0.M1 correctly from the same source you have mentioned and used this for spring-cql:

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cql</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: @mp911de Even after changing spring-cql version to 1.5.0.M1, I am still getting errors:

Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [localhost/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect))

And also:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.util.AttributeKey.valueOf(Ljava/lang/String;)Lio/netty/util/AttributeKey;

Comment: Seems you also need to upgrade netty. `cassandra-driver-core` references netty `4.0.37.Final`

Comment: @mp911de Yes I have excluded netty-handler and netty-transport-native-epoll from cassandra-driver-core and added latest versions of these libraries (4.1.4.Final). Still getting exact same error.

Comment: Please use Netty 4.0.x. I'm not sure whether the Cassandra driver is compatible with 4.1

Comment: @mp911de Yes even on adding netty's 4.0.40.Final(latest of 4.0.x versions), getting exact same error

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible test case/provide some code to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially I have forgotten to add CassandraConfig class (http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/1.5.0.M1/reference/html/#cassandra-connectors.javaconfig) which was not the part of sample provided by spring-boot. So now it works.